# Mage::getStoreConfig always returns null for my custom module admin option

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.7

I have a module: `app/code/local/Namespace/Resize/`

so I've included a option to disable/enable an option through Magento admin.

`System > Configuration > Namespace > Resize`

but when I try to access to this option I always receives an NULL with `Mage::getStoreConfig` although the option is set to Yes.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('resize/settings/enabled', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

or

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('resize/settings/enabled');
```

returns NULL

`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Resize>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Resize>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <resize>
              <class>Namespace_Resize_Helper</class>
            </resize>
        </helpers>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
              <observers>
                <resize>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>namespace_resize_model_observer</class>
                  <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
                </resize>
              </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

`system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <resizing module="resize" translate="label">
            <label>Resize</label>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </resizing>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <resize module="resize" translate="label">
            <label>Resize</label>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <tab>resizing</tab>
            <groups>
                <settings module="resize" translate="label">
                    <label>Settings</label>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="Enable resize">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <comment>Backend Resizing</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                    </fields>
                </settings>
            </groups>
        </resize>
    </sections>
</config>
```

`adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <resize>
                                        <title>Resize Settings</title>
                                    </resize>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                 </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

`helper app/code/local/Namespace/Resize/Helper/Data`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Resize_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

- Module is working fine
- Cached is disabled
- I'm sure the option is saved because I can see an entry in the database that is updated.

```
config id | scope  | scope id | path                    | value
785       | stores | 1        | resize/settings/enabled | 1
```

Anyone can help me what's wrong?

thanks

Comment: What does Mage::getStoreConfigFlag() give you?

Comment: thanks, always returns false

Comment: are you still having an issue? if so where are you calling the getStoreConfig?

Comment: I tested on backend side, I mean magento admin but when I tested on frontend it works as expected! now I know that it does not works on backend but I did not want to stay with the doubt

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP my admin and make sure you setting is saved on core_config_data table

Use this query

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` where path like "%YOUR_CONFIG_FIELD_NAME%";
```

and make sure you will find your setting. If not then something is wrong on your module side.

Answer (score -1):

Would you like to rename this tag name in your system.xml file

```
<tabs>
    <resizing module="resize" translate="label">
        <label>Resize</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </resizing>
</tabs>
```

Replace resizing with resize

and try again.